# Incorrect check boxes redirect

Tags: javascript

Someone can tell me what is wrong with the function below?

```
<form name="Menu" id="menu" onsubmit="this.enviar();">
<select id="pais" name="pais" size="1"">
  <option value="polonia">Polónia</option>
  <option value="portugal">Portugal</option>
  <option value="reino-unido">Reino Unido</option>
</select>
<select id="area" name="area" size="1">
  <option value="#">Seleciona uma área </option>
  <option value="arquitetura">Arquitetura</option>
  <option value="comunicacao">Comunicação</option>
  <option value="design">Design</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Pesquisar"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function vai(link) { location.href= link; }
function enviar(){
var pais = document.menu.pais.value;
var area = document.menu.area.value;
           window.location.href("http://www.teste.pt/tag/"+pais+"+"+area);
}
// ]]></script>
```

Instead of going to the link `http://www.teste.pt/tag/pais+area`, do this: `http://teste.pt/?pais=holanda&area=informatica`

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the target `href` in the `enviar()` function. Since the variables are becoming part of the querystring, it is recommend to wrap them in `encodeURIComponent` as well so they are properly encoded for that purpose.

```
function enviar(){
  // Also recommend using getElementById() to get these nodes
  var pais = document.getElementById("pais").value;
  var area = document.getElementById("area").value;
  window.location.href("http://teste.pt?pais=" + encodeURIComponent(pais) + "&area=" + encodeURIComponent(area));
}
```

#### Update after comments:

If you want to the JavaScript to continue redirecting to the same link `http://www.teste.pt/tag/"+pais+"+"+area` but internally process it as `http://teste.pt/?pais=holanda&area=informatica`, that must be done with a rewrite rule.  If you are using Apache, the following should go into your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/([^+]+)\+(.*)$ /?pais=$1&area=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @JoãoNascimento Your question says _instead of going to ..., do this: ..._, which I interpreted as you wanted it to go to the second link. What is it doing now?

Comment: Sorry I still exchange a few words. What I want is to go to a link with this structure: http://teste.pt/tag/{pais-selected}+{area-selected}.

And the result of the code is: http://teste.pt/?pais={pais-selected}&area={area-selected}

Comment: @JoãoNascimento That cannot be done with JavaScript, it must be handled with a rewrite by the web server. See above.

Comment: @JoãoNascimento The RewriteRule assumes there is an index.php which receives the URL parameters.  But the web server must rewrite it first.